# jquerymobile remove hidden pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I'm trying to remove some Hidden pages, here is my code.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
     $(document).bind("pagehide", function () {
          // At this stage works fine, but Don't know how to reference the hidden page
          alert("Hello world");      
     });
 });
```

The question is what is the correct way to reference the page that was hide?
It is possible to list only the pages using each()?

Comment: It looks like you grab the entire element with `ui.prevPage`. Add the arguments `events, ui` to your pagehide callback functions parameters, `$(document).bind('pagehide', function(events, ui)`. You should also then be able to say `$(ui.prevPage).remove();` to remove this page from the DOM, but not sure why you would want to do that / if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Very tks ... I want to delete it because some pages are causing that external pages doesn't refresh properly after at each call. All my pages are dinamically created. Thats the reason why I want to delete it. If you have another aproach you are welcome.... Very tks for your answer. TKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

  $.mobile.document.bind('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
    $(event.target).remove();
  });

});
```